# Unable to open activity from Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I an trying to open activity from widget but Unable to open  activity when i click on widget button,My code is given below

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        // retrieve a ref to the manager so we can pass a view update

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.avion.mychurch", "com.avion.mychurch.Welcome");
        PendingIntent myPI = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        // intent to start service

        // Get the layout for the App Widget
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main);

        // attach the click listener for the service start command intent
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wid_launch, myPI);

        // define the componenet for self
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MainActivity.class.getName());

        // tell the manager to update all instances of the toggle widget with
        // the click listener
        mgr.updateAppWidget(comp, views);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never provide any code for actually starting an activity. 
Add this and the activity should start when you click it:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views(R.id.the_id_of_a_view_in_your_activity_main_layout, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thx for replay but i am new to coding , can u please provide content for full onupdate method?

Comment: Can't be more simple then to just copy the lines I wrote and replace the the_id_of_a_view_in_your_activity_main_layout with a id from a view inside your activity_main